# amazon ec2 Attach and detach a server from load balancer in Amazon aws in shell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Attach and detach a server from load balancer in Amazon aws in shell script

```
 #!/bin/bash
 if[build_server_response=true];then
         ##  DETACH FROM LOAD BALANCE R

         perform_server_update;

         ## ATTACH BACK TO LOAD BALANCE R
 if
```

i have set up amazon ec2 tools in my debain system but what are commands to Attach and detach a server from load balancer in Amazon aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are:

```
aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/register-instances-with-load-balancer.html

```
aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/deregister-instances-from-load-balancer.html

Comment: aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer --load-balancer-name  --instances